# Array returns the first element char instead of the whole element

Tags: arrays, powershell

I defined an `Array`:

```
function GetNames
{
    $names = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $names += "Drin"
    $names
}
```

Now I want to take the first name from the `Array`:

```
$names = GetNames
$firstName = $names[0]
```

So now `$firstName` instead of receive `Drin` I got `D`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you retrieve the type of `$names` using `GetType()` you will see that `$names` is actually a string - thus you get the first character if you are accessing the first index:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType 
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

**Note:** This is because you only have a *single element in the pipeline*. To force `$names` to be an array, you have to *explicitly* declare it:

```
$names = @(GetNames)
```

Also note that you don't have to use `New-Object` to create an array. You can also declare it using:

```
function GetNames
{
    @('Drin')
}
```

Comment: also a fun way to do that: `$names = ,(GetNames)`

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code as-is, but put a `$names.GetType()` in between each line your get this:

```
$names = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$names.GetType()
$names += "Drin"
$names.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                           
True     True     ArrayList                                System.Object                                                                                                                      
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

By calling `$names += "Drin"` you have redefined the type of `$names`. It's not intuitive (at least to me as a C# dev), but that's what's happened.

If you did it with the `.Add(...)` method then it would work fine:

```
$names = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$names.GetType()
$names.Add("Drin")
$names.GetType()
$names[0]
```

This gives:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                           
True     True     ArrayList                                System.Object                                                                                                                      
0
True     True     ArrayList                                System.Object                                                                                                                      
Drin
```

The type of `$names` stays the same and you get the correct result out.

The correct way is to avoid using `ArrayList` (it is so 2001 afterall). Instead do it with `@()`. Try this:

```
$names = @()
$names.GetType()
$names += "Drin"
$names.GetType()
$names[0]
```

That gives:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                           
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                                                                                       
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                                                                                       
Drin
```

As Martin pointed out in the comments, the function should look like this:

```
function GetNames
{
    $names = @()
    $names += "Drin"
    $names
}
```

Comment: @MartinBrandl - How so?

Comment: If you copy his function and paste your code into it and invoke it using `$names = GetNames` you will see that `$names[0]` still returns `D´. This is because you have to cast the *return*  value from the function to an array. So thats the actual issue here (beside that what you mentioned he could also just use @())

Comment: @MartinBrandl - Sorry, my intention by putting `$names[0]` was to show, if you ran that block of code, that you got the string back. I wasn't trying to show the body of the function. You're right, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately sometimes the only solution is to declare the variable as [array] and use += (without blanks)
When the array is filled with only **one** value I am not able to see the whole element with $arg.id[0].

working: `[array]$arg+=(Get-AzApplicationGateway)`

**not** working:`[array]$arg += (Get-AzApplicationGateway)`

Only this will give me back the first element of `$arg.id[0]` and not only the first character of the string.
This looks really buggy in fact that it is only working without blanks for me in `$PSVersionTable` 5.1.19041.906